# Powershell: get items from a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I'm struggling with weird issue, I'm trying to get the items from a list on a sharepoint Site, I made a very simple script for testing purpose:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$WebURL = "https://mysharepointsite.com"
$listName = "Users"

$list = (Get-SPWeb $WebURL).Lists.TryGetList($ListName)
 
$items = $list.GetItems()


Write-Host $items.Count
write-Host $list.ItemCount
```

So my list exist and it contains 27 items (I check that manually), the $items.count return a null value but $list.itemCount returns 27
If I tried with another list on the same site, everything works perfectly, any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Permissions could be the issue. As SharePoint provide item level permission, to use $list.GetItems() make sure you have permissions to the list items.

Reference: https://mywaysharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/05/23/difference-between-splist-itemcount-and-splist-items-count/